# What is the best method to use AJAX function on cordova apps?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm using $.get method for all of my AJAX function,
Example :

```
function getNotified() {
    spinner();
    $.get("http://www.easlyid.com/webservice.php", {
        ajx: "getNotified",
        email: localStorage.getItem("login_email")
    }, function (result) {
        alert(result);
        $("#mainContent").html(result);
        unspinner();
    });
}
```

What's the difference between `$.get` and `$.ajax`?

In my situation which one should i use? `$.get` or `$.ajax`?
and what is the best method to do a "AJAX Call" on cordova android apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'best' method per se. What's important though is that the http method used is correct.

`$.get` is the shorthand jQuery call for HTTP GET request. There are `$.post` as well for HTTP POST request. Use `$.ajax` if you need more customisation on your call to backend, like having a custom HTTP Method.

Here's jQuery documentation on this:

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

For the differences between GET and POST, refer here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

Simple explaination on GET vs POST:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Hope this helps.